# ASP.Net GridView GridViewDeleteEventArgs.Keys empty

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have following Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table" DataKeyNames="groupId"
          DataSource="<%# dsUserGroupsSelected %>" DataMember="Group" etc....>
```

and after firing RowDeleting event handler:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
```

e.Keys is empty. Moreover, in runtime if I check

```
dsUserGroupsSelected.Group.PrimaryKey
```

it is poulated with:

```
{System.Data.DataColumn[1]}
    [0]: {groupId}
```

so it's really odd to me. Am I missing something? I have this kind of a workaround:

```
int groupId = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;
```

which will work just fine, but I just can't get it why e.Keys (and e.Values) would be empty!? Any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking for a resolution to this as well. If a user deletes a record and then hits F5, the next record will be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this behaviour is intentional.

From http://forums.asp.net/p/1050092/2128091.aspx

> Looking in Reflector at Gridview.HandleDelete(), it appears that
>   e.Keys and e.Values are only populated if
>   gridview.IsBoundUsingDataSourceID. That is, if you set the DataSource
>   in code then none of this will work. Good one, Microsoft! Might have
>   been useful to mention that in the help perhaps??!! Lachlan

Edit:

I ended up making my own data objects and put them in the app_code folder

ex.

```
public class CustomDataViews
{
    public class FileQuery
    {
        public class File
        {
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public string Path { get; set; }
            public void Delete() { }
        }

        public ArrayList GetFiles()
        {
            System.Collections.ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UserUpload/"));
            foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in (from a in di.GetFiles() orderby a.CreationTime descending select a))
            {
                File myFile = new File();
                myFile.CreatedDate = fi.CreationTime;
                myFile.FileName = fi.Name;
                myFile.Path = "/VACWeb/UserUpload/" + fi.Name;
                files.Add(myFile);
            }
            return files;
        }

        public void Delete(string FileName)
        {
            if (FileName != null)
            {
                string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UserUpload/") + FileName;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="FileName"
    DataSourceID="ods1">
    <Columns>
        <cc:ExtendedCommandField DeleteConfirmationText="Are you sure you wish to delete this file?"
            DeleteText="Delete" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="Created Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="Path" AlternateText="No Image" HeaderText="Image Preview"
            ControlStyle-Width="100px">
            <ControlStyle Width="100px" />
        </asp:ImageField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Path" HeaderText="Path" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="Path" DataTextField="FileName" HeaderText="Link" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="Delete" SelectMethod="GetFiles"
    TypeName="CustomDataViews+FileQuery">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FileName" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple! ASP is a big piece of .... and GridView is a small piece in the big peace. Have the same problem, and while the workaround is ok for deleting, updating becomes really interesting... The actual problem is it seems that for no good or apparent reason a looooooooot of the functionality of GridView is missing if the DataSource is not a DataSourceControl: Like filling the keys & values properties in the eventargs. Enjoy! Viva Microsoft!

Comment: It didn't really help, but I'm happy we can share the pain :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you're programatically sorting your gridview in your Page_Load method? If so, try moving the sort into the Page_Init method, and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I see the idea, but unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the GridViewDeleteEventArgs.Keys property only works if you set the GridView's DataSource by setting the **DataSourceID** property -- i.e. setting the **DataSource** property and then manually calling DataBind() leaves the Keys property (and the Values property as well) empty.

*Source:* http://forums.asp.net/t/1050092.aspx